# Comparing two column List<> based on column one

Tags: c#, sql, list, sqldatareader

I'm trying to compare two SQL databases together using C#.
I am storing the List of fields from the first Database in a two column list.
How would I go about matching the two columns from one List to the other? Both databases output Lists with the exact same following two columns (CustNo, CustName).

CustNo is the primary key so I would like to iterate through all CustNo fields and find if the CustName has been changed.

```
using static ESLBlackBox.MasterReport;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program program = new Program();

        var changed = program.ReadNewMasterReport()
            .Where(b => program.ReadOldMasterReport()
            .Any(a => a.custNo == b.custNo && a.custName != b.custName))
            .ToList();

        Console.WriteLine(changed);
    }

    public List<Fields> ReadOldMasterReport()
    {
        SqlDataReader rdr = null;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ESLAXSQLDEV1;Initial Catalog=ESLBlackBox;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Master_Report", conn);
        List<Fields> oldResult = new List<Fields>();

        try
        {
            using (conn)
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader != null && reader.Read())
                    {
                        oldResult.Add(new Fields
                        {
                            custNo = Convert.ToString(reader["Service Address Cust No"]),
                            custName = Convert.ToString(reader["Service Address Acct Name"])
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (rdr != null)
            {
                rdr.Close();
            }

            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        return oldResult;
    }
```

MasterReport Class

```
class MasterReport
{
    public class Fields
    {
        public string custNo { get; set; }
        public string custName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to do that in DB or in memory?

Comment: Probably in memory. What would be faster? We could potentially be iterating through 100,000 + lines.

Comment: You are getting it wrong! Your class (Fields) has TWO properties, so it represents ONE ROW in the table. In your loop, you should assign both columns into the same instance of the new object that you are creating.

Comment: if those two databases are on the same server then you might be able to compare using a cross database join. This is way faster than doing so in memory

Comment: @Steve Yes databases are on the same server.

Comment: do you want to find the entries in table 1 but not in table 2?

Comment: @Steve I want to find the entries in Table 2 that have changed.

Comment: @Sparrow Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the code above to reflect putting the two properties on the same row.

Comment: OK, so now you have ONE list that contains the data for the table in ONE database. You need to create another list just like this one for the table in the other database. After that is done, you can use the answer that Brandon Miller has provided

Comment: @Sparrow This has been done already. I didn't put the code up above as its exactly the same as the ReadOldMasterReport() method. Its just called ReadNewMasterReport(). var changed = program.ReadNewMasterReport()
                .Where(b => program.ReadOldMasterReport()
                .Any(a => a.custNo == b.custNo && a.custName != b.custName))
                .ToList();

Comment: So after you create the lists and call Brandon's code, the 'changed' is empty?

Comment: It never manages to get through the 'changed' section. The program just hangs like its trying to compare all of the changes. It never gets to the Console.WriteLine(changed.Count); underneath the Linq code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use linq for this:

```
var changed = listB
    .Where(b => listA
        .Any(a => a.custNo == b.custNo && a.custName != b.custName))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, however, nothing seems to happen when it executes this code. Could it potentially be taking a long time to compare? There are currently only 600 records in each database table. Updated the code above to show how it was called in case I did it wrong.

Comment: changed is a List. Instead, Console.Writeline(changed.Count) or something like that.

Comment: It never gets to the Console.WriteLine(changed.Count) line as it stays on the above linq code.

Comment: Instead of putting the program.ReadMasterReport() and the other in inside of the linq call, I'd make actual objects out of them and use them instead. I'd say it isn't getting hung up in the linq itself - especially not for only 600 rows, but it's probably getting hung up somewhere in your sql.

Comment: Thanks, @Brandon Miller, you were right. The data was wiping one of the return values out when it returned the next database. Fixed with objects and the Linq code works well.

Answer (score 0):

Since the two DBs are on the same server you can do a cross DB join to find out the difference.

```
SELECT tb1.CustNo, tb1.CustName, tb2.CustName FROM db1.dbo.Master_Report tb1 INNER JOIN db2.dbo.Master_Report tb2 ON tb1.CustNo = tb2.CustNo WHERE tb1.CustName != tb2.CustName;
```

this way you are avoiding loading hundreds of thousands entries and compare them in memory. Database will do the dirty work for you.